# How to display Samsung DeX onto a laptop monitor?

Tags: android

I am trying to display my phone's Samsung DeX onto my laptop display instead of an external monitor.

Is this possible? If yes, then how?

The laptop already has an operating system (Windows 10) on it.

Is there a way I can plug my phone into my laptop and display Samsung DeX onto it or maybe even through WiFi?

Comment: Hi Avinash, welcome. I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow is not the place for such step-by-step guides. You need to give way more and precise information, including what you have tried, and the specific problems you're encountering. This makes it much easier for anyone to help you.

Comment: @Edward I have updated , Please help.

Comment: Hi Avinash, I'm afraid your edit is not really substantial enough to help anyone help you. You should edit your post to show the precise problem(s) you have, and the steps you have already taken, and how they failed. Your question might otherwise risk getting deleted.

Comment: Most laptop's HDMI connectors are not video-in for displaying things from external sources on the laptop's screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the question is not particularly clearly worded at this time, I'm guessing that you're trying to use the laptop screen as an external monitor for the mobile device.

Most laptops do not support this function at all or in any way.

Basically, the video connector on the laptop is essentially a send-only connector. It connects to the GPU and works to send information from that GPU to the external monitor. A computer screen, on the other hand, accepts those signals and, with minimal additional processing, sends them on to the display. A laptop does not accept these signals.

There are specialized software which may allow a laptop or other computer screen to act as additional monitors to a different computer device, but these would not happen over the HDMI connector and would more likely require a data connection such as USB or Ethernet and there would be substantial amounts of lag involved.